# Is there any RasPi image with integrated OpenCV libraries, to avoid compilation task of OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi

There are number of tutorials online which can tell you how to setup openCV on RasPi. But the process itself is time consuming as it involves compilation of all modules.

So, i am hoping that there must be someone maintaining the RasPi images with openCV libraries integrated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution i was looking for. I wanted to avoid compilation task for opencv libraries, as on RasPi it take like 9-11 hours. Looking over internet regarding installing opencv on Raspi, everybody was directing towards compilation steps.

[OpenCV installation easy way](https://hackaday.io/project/7008-fly-wars-a-hackers-solution-to-world-hunger/log/23068-installing-opencv-on-a-raspberry-pi-the-easy-way), here i finally found the instruction, to install opencv libraries directly. Then i tried a simple example of reading an image using OpenCV, everything was working smooth.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install libcv-dev
sudo apt-get install python-opencv
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev
sudo apt-get install libcv2.3
sudo apt-get install opencv-doc
```

I hope it may help someone, as i spent quite a time looking for this.